# ":"-Character in a windows filesystem (formerly: ":"-Character in Delphi TFileStream)

Tags: windows, filesystems, character, filenames

I tried to put a colon in the String of the filename of a filestream.
Is it true that one can't use a colon in a TFileStream in Delphi?
And if you can, then how?

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the downvotes. It deserves that. In retrospekt I have asked a stupid question...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This has nothing to do with Delphi, nor programming. The question you should have ask was if you can use a colon in the name of a file on Windows.

Comment: I'm sorry! I should have known!

Comment: Now that I was reminded of what the actual problem is, it seems like a stupid question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, which I presume is your platform, the colon is a reserved character and so not allowed in a filename. This is documented here:

[File and Directory Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#file_and_directory_names)

> **Naming Conventions**
>   The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:
>
> ...
>
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), **except for the following**:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - < (less than)
>     - > (greater than)
>     - **: (colon)**
>     - " (double quote)
>     - / (forward slash)
>     - \ (backslash)
>     - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - ? (question mark)
>     - * (asterisk)
>
> ...

Comment: As TLama says, the issue is specific to the Windows file system, not a Delphi issue per se.  In these days of multi-platform support (and the OP tagged XE5 which has such support) we perhaps should be a bit more precise in our answers in respect of what is a Delphi issue and what is a platform issue.  Delphi itself makes no reservations w.r.t. filename characters, a colon is permitted in filenames on some Delphi supported platforms, e.g. OS X (though not recommended for obvious reasons).  Perhaps add a clarification along these lines ?